# How to push a cloned repo from one version control to another?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, gitlab

I cloned a source code which was hosted on heroku and is on bit bucket:

Say **myapp**

The cloned app is the employer's copy but I want to have my own copy and my own version control. So I am trying to create a new project on **GitLab** and push the copy of this file to the newly created project on Gitlab.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to create a new repo on `GitLab`, then, with the new repository URL in hands and at the local repository, execute the following commands:

```
git remote add origin <remote repository URL>
git push -u origin master
```

The `-u` option used in the `push` is to add upstream (tracking) reference, so you can do `git pull` later without specifying `origin`.